# Get local variable to show date + days with YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss

Tags: oracle, date, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to get v_återdatum to show sysdate+p_dagar in  "YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss" but i don't know how to do it. I was able to do it with just YYYY-MM-DD, but I don't know how to get the seconds in as well.

This is what i got at the moment:

```
create or replace
function get_återdatum(
p_dagar number)
return date
as
v_återdatum date;
v_datum date := sysdate;
begin
v_återdatum:=to_date(v_datum, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'+ p_dagar) ;

return v_återdatum;

end;
```

I'm not getting hh12:mi:ss in the output when I call the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `v_datum` is of date type, and `p_dagar` is a number. You can add a number to a date and the result will be a date.
So, your function body will be simply,

```
v_återdatum := v_datum + p_dagar;
```

This returned date will contain the time part, but may not be displayed based on the NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter, which you can check using this query.

```
select *
  from v$nls_parameters
 where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';
```

It is always better to explicitly specify the display format using TO_CHAR function.

```
select to_char(get_återdatum(7), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual;
```